# Integration of Active directory with OIM

Tags: oim

If the connector server and Active directory is installed in the same Windows server then what are the advantages and disadvantages of the same.

Thanks in advance....

Sangita

Answer (score 1):

1. What is Connector Server?

   With reference to ICF connectors the connector server is mediator between your OIM and target applications. If we specify connector server details while configuring the IT resource of application, then all request generated for that external application are handle by the connector server.

Advantages:-

1. Light and simple to implement.
2. Extensible
3. Performance Improvement

Now talking about the decision where to place the connector server. Its always good to have connector server installed on separate box other that active directory server. The reason being it will have high CPU utilization for both the operations performed on connector server and active directory.